# Strange memory leak related to CanvasControl

Tags: uwp, win2d

I have managed to isolate a strange problem in a very small test project. All the code is in codebehind, below.

The main point is that if on the button press, I replace the MainGrid content with a new grid, and add a new CanvasControl to that secondary new grid, I get no memory leak.

But if instead I replace a CanvasInGrid object, which inherits Grid, and adds a canvas to it's own content, each time I press the button, the object count for CanvasInGrid and CanvasControl increases as seen by the Diagnostic Tools / Memory usage / take snapshot

But if I add a button instead in CanvasInGrid, again there is no memory leak.

I can only put this down as a bug in CanvasControl? Or am I missing something? Is there a safe way to prevent this problem when adding a canvascontrol in this way?

Even if I catch CanvasInGrid_Unloaded and set Canvas = nothing, the Canvas count seems not to increase but I get some other things increasing including the CanvasInGrid:

IntPtr  +1  +12 +12 12  144 144

ConditionalWeakTable +1  +32 +216    12  384 2,592

ConditionalWeakTable+Container   +1  +184    +184    12  2,208   2,208

WindowsRuntimeMarshal+NativeOrStaticEventRegistrationImpl+TokenListCount    +1  +20 +20 12  240 240

WindowsRuntimeMarshal+NativeOrStaticEventRegistrationImpl+EventRegistrationTokenListWithCount   +1  +24 +24 12  288 288

App1.CanvasInGrid   +1  +20 +20 6   120 144

```
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

    Private sp As New StackPanel
    Private MainGrid As New Grid

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Content = sp
        Dim b As New Button
        b.Content = "test"
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf test
        sp.Children.Add(b)
        sp.Children.Add(MainGrid)

        Application.Current.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = False

    End Sub


    Private Sub test(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        MainGrid.Children.Clear()

        'this does NOT cause a leak
        'Dim testgr = New Grid
        'Dim canv As New CanvasControl
        'testgr.Children.Add(canv)
        'gr.Children.Add(testgr)


        'this DOES cause a leak
        MainGrid.Children.Add(New CanvasInGrid)

    End Sub

End Class



Public Class CanvasInGrid
    Inherits Grid

    Public button As Button
    Public Canvas As CanvasControl

    Public Sub New()
        Canvas = New CanvasControl
        'button = New Button 'if I do this with a button instead of the Canvas there is no leak

        Children.Add(Canvas)
        'Children.Add(button)
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: I am now finding results are inconsistent, I can see the leak with the button, but still always with the CanvasInGrid and never with the MainGrid and content added separately

Comment: I note that uniquely, CanvasControl has "RemoveFromVisualTree" to release resources. But Calling that doesn't help.

Comment: I tested your code, but it worked fine and there was no memory leak. Can you provide information about your development environment? For example, the minimum running version of the application and the target running version?

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Maybe memory leak in `MainGrid.Children.Add(New CanvasInGrid)`

Comment: The win2d have to remove from visual tree manual. Try to call `canvas.RemoveFromVisualTree` to remove it. See https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/RefCycles.htm

Comment: I am using the latest versions for everything, target and min version = 18362, Win2D.uwp = 1.23, and just tried new update 1.24. "New CanvasInGrid" is just a grid, there should be no references to it once it is removed when the next one is added "MainGrid.Children.Clear()"

Comment: I am sorry that I still can't reproduce this question based on your code. You can try to create a instance which not meet the memory leak issue, or you can ask the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D/issues) to win2d.